# search and replace block to a line

Tags: replace, register, multiple-lines

I would like to replace a multiline block to one line

for example :

```
    if (... ){
     //comment0
     line1
     line2
   }
   some code
   if (... ){
     //comment0
     line1
     line2
   }
```

into:

```
if_function()
some code
if_function()
```

is there a fast way to do this?
I tried to yank the block into register

```
 shift+V
 4j
 "fy
```

and then replace, but I don't know how to reference the register
tried:

```
%s/@f/if_function/g
```

and

```
%s/\@f/if_function/g
```

and

```
%s/"f/if_function/g
```

and

```
%s/\"f/if_function/g
```

but they all doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found how to paste register
ctrl+r

so I enter to visual mode, and marked the block

```
shift+ v
4j
```

and used the replace command:

```
:%s/^Rf/if_function/g
```

Answer (score 1):

How I would probably approach this:

1. Navigate: possibly something like `/if` then `$`; the goal is to be on the curly brace for the `%` key. Or you could just get inside the curlies for `a{`
2. Change: `cV%` or `cVa{` and type `if_function()`
3. Change populates a register. If I had more of the same edit, I would first navigate again (maybe `n`?) and then `.` to repeat. When I’m done, paste the original content somewhere with `p` if I were, for example, extracting a function. (Actually, I might have yanked it, pasted it, and created the function before starting all the changes, but since `c` does fill a register we can do things in this order, which almost seems like what you’re looking for.)

Comment: thanks for the answer
but I wanted to do it in one command,
and I found it in my answer